# FlutterMacOS.h not found - Firebase Core error when building flutter project on MacOS

Tags: flutter, firebase, macos

I've been having trouble building a flutter project on MacOS. I have now created a brand new flutter project, added the firebase/firestore packages below in my pubspec and when building on MacOS I get the error shown.

My Mac OS Version is the latest Ventura `13.2.1`. Has Apple M1 chip.

**Error:**

```
2 warnings generated.
/Users/alexprice/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-2.13.0/macos/Classes/messages.g.m:9:9: fatal error: 'FlutterMacOS/FlutterMacOS.h' file not found
#import <FlutterMacOS/FlutterMacOS.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Libuv-gRPC' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Flutter Assemble' from project 'Runner')
** BUILD FAILED **
```

Running very latest of everything. `Flutter 3.10.2`, latest Xcode. I have tried `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get`, removed lock files, `pod reintegrate`, `pod update`, `pod repo update`, `pod install`.. I have added necessary Google-services json file for firebase even though it doesn't even get this far to read it.

**Pubspec.yaml**

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.1 <4.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  cloud_firestore: ^4.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^4.6.1
  firebase_core: ^2.13.0
  firebase_storage: ^11.2.1
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.3.6
```

I've even added necessary modifications to pod file so pod builds are minimum `12.0`:

**macOS Pod File:**

```
platform :osx, '12.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'ephemeral', 'Flutter-Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure \"flutter pub get\" is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Flutter-Generated.xcconfig, then run \"flutter pub get\""
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_macos_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_macos_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        # config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=macos]"] = "arm64"
        config.build_settings['MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
        config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'YES'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I believe it was due to having my Github folder in my Documents on my Mac. When files are backed up to the cloud I believe it was causing issues so moved my GitHub folder to my Home folder instead, made a new project and worked